# How can I improve accuracy of the GPS location?

Tags: android, gps, location

When I open my app and press a button I want it to request a single location solely from the GPS to get the most accurate location possible. I did the following:

```
LocationManager mlocManager =    (LocationManager)GetActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);                 
if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {                      
   LocationListener mlocListener = new LocationManagerHelper(...); 
   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);//accuracy fine calls accuracy high
   mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria,mlocListener,null);
}
```

When I open the GPS inside my house, go to the window and !only then! I press that button, I get a location far from me with the accuracy of 300-900! I thought that maybe a second request will improve it but even 4-5 requests remains on the same spot with the same low accuracy, also, the other requests are very fast as if it didn't really ask the GPS again for a location but took it from the cache of some sort.

If I open the GPS while I'm already near the window, the location is better and sometimes I get to accuracy of 20-30, the thing is, that even then, sometimes the accuracy is not that high so I was wondering how can I initialize the GPS/location so if I get a bad accuracy in the first try, at least it will give me a better one on the second try.

Thanks

Comment: [You can try this way](http://www.androidpit.com/how-to-improve-your-gps-signal-on-your-android)

Comment: You are talking about the device's GPS, I was wondering how can I do it via code (Java/Android)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the LocationManager is using cached data like you suggest.

You could try using the requestLocationUpdates() method on LocationManager instead. If you just require the one location fix, then disable the locationUpdates by calling the removeUpdates() method
after first callback to LocationListener.

This approach will also allow you to wait for a location that has sufficient accuracy. The following code shows how to filter locations if the accuracy is too low for your needs.

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location.getAccuracy() > THRESHOLD) {
            return;
        }

        //Act on location data here

        //Then remove the updates once done
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};
```

Comment: what value do you suggest for THRESHOLD (20,50,100 or 200)?